# checkpointing the model every iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

what is the best practice for checkpointing (i.e. save an snapshot of) the model every Nth iteration in TensorFlow?

obviously, it is possible to do it using custom logic to call `tf.train.Saver.save` but was wondering if there is an internal mechanism for that?

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this based upon how often I want the checkpoint saved:

```
if (epoch % N) == (N - 1):
    saveto=CkptDir+"ckpt/model"+str(N)+".ckpt"
    save_path = saverRun.save(session, saveto)
```

This will save a checkpoint file ever N epoch's.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver). It is possible to set `max_to_keep` and `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours` to get a desired saving.